# CSS/JQUERY flip transition effect change direction

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

currently the transition slides from left to right. And idea how I would make it appear that it goes from top to bottom?

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/lakario/VPjX9/

Here is some of the css code:

```css
.flip {
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0); 
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-transform:translateX(0);
}
.flip.in.reverse {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipintoleft;
    -moz-animation-name: flipintoleft;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipouttoleft {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipouttoleft {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipouttoright {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) ; }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipouttoright {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipintoleft {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipintoleft {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipintoright {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipintoright {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
```

Comment: Look into animate.css http://daneden.me/animate/, The flipX function on there does the effect you are looking for.

Comment: You mean like http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/VPjX9/286/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

http://jsfiddle.net/VPjX9/289/

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it, but I just changed the rotate Y values in your CSS to rotate X, so it's along the X axis.

Example:
Was:

```
@-moz-keyframes flipintoleft {
from { -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(.9); }
to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }}
```

Now is:

```
@-moz-keyframes flipintoleft {
from { -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(.9); }
to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `rotateY`, use `rotateX`, which will fix the axis horizontally, instead of vertically.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VPjX9/287/

If you want it to rotate the other way, just switch -90deg for 90deg and vice versa.